# I need to transfer a very large folder over FTP, without creating a file first

Tags: pipe, tar, ftp

I am running an Amazon EC2 instance that is limited in disk space. I have a very large folder that I need to FTP to my local machine, preferably without creating an intermediate tar file, since there might not be enough disk space.

Can I use a pipe for this?

**Note** While FTP isn't the best way of transferring the files, is my only option in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Use just about any FTP client other than the basic `ftp` program.

- Store your password in [`~/.netrc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc) and use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/):

  ```
  wget -r ftp://username@example.com/path/to/directory
  ```

  Keep in mind that the `-r` option has a default maximum depth of 5. You can use `-l` to increase it.
- Use [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/):

  ```
  open username@example.com
  mirror /path/to/directory
  ```
- Use [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/):

  ```
  open -u username example.com
  get -R /path/to/directory
  ```

  Or its `ncftpget` command:

  ```
  ncftpget ftp://username@example.com//path/to/directory
  ```

Alternatively, mount the FTP server as a directory and access it like you would any other directory. There are several [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystems for FTP.

- [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/):

  ```
  mountavfs
  cat file_containing_your_password >~/.avfs/#ftp_ctl:username@example.com/password
  cp -Rp ~/.avfs/#ftp:username@example.com/path/to/directory .
  ```
- [CURLFTPFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/): store your password in [`~/.netrc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc), then

  ```
  mkdir ~/example.com
  curlftpfs -o user=username example.com ~/example.com
  cp -Rp example.com/path/to/directory .
  ```

Comment: Using mget with the basic ftp clients should work for one directory (but not sub directories).

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of transfer FTP may not be your best choice.  Using `rsync` or `scp` may work better for this.  Try something like:

```
scp -r user@host:folder  .
```

If you need to fetch updates from the server, then `rsync` should work better.

EDIT:  If you are stuck with FTP, then the use a recursive `wget` command, or get an FTP client which supports recursive gets.

Comment: For all kinds of transfers FTP is not the best choice!

Comment: I know it's not best, but that's the system I have. The FTP server is running on a NAS and I can't change that.